# Mass Import Data from Excel file to Access programmatically in C#

Tags: database, excel, ms-access

Given the fact that Excel and Access are compatible in some level, is there a way to import data from an excel file to an Access Database programmatically, without reading the file and inserting data, record by record?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very roughly:

```
string ConnString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Z:\Docs\Test.accdb";
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnString);
conn.Open();
string sql = @"select * into newxl from [Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=Z:\Docs\Test.xlsx].[Sheet1$] s;";

OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandText = sql;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```